# Python: Select keys in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary with the following structure:

```
topHitsDict = 
{'record301': 
    {'query': 'OBGP2018240_Oncorhynchus.clarkii',
        'hit1': 
            {'description': 'OBGP-2018-240_Oncorhynchus.clarkii',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
        'hit2': 
            {'description': 'OBGP-2017-332_Oncorhynchus.clarkii',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
    'numTopHits': 2},
'record302': 
    {'query': 'OBGP2018248_Oncorhynchus.kisutch',
        'hit1': 
            {'description': 'OBGP-2018-248_Oncorhynchus.kisutch',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
        'hit2': 
            {'description': 'OBGP-2018-038_Oncorhynchus.kisutch',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
        'hit3': 
            {'description': 'OBGP-2017-271_Oncorhynchus.kisutch',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
    'numTopHits': 3},
'record303':
    {'query': 'OBGP2019056_Oncorhynchus.tshawytscha',
       'hit1':
            {'description': 'OBGP-2019-056_Oncorhynchus.tshawytscha',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
        'hit2':
            {'description': 'OBGP-2017-356_Oncorhynchus.tshawytscha',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
        'hit3': 
            {'description': 'OBGP-2017-052_Oncorhynchus.tshawytscha',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
    'numTopHits': 3},
'record304':
    {'query': 'OBGP2019190_Oncorhynchus.nerka',
        'hit1': 
            {'description': 'OBGP-2019-191_Oncorhynchus.nerka',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
        'hit2': 
            {'description': 'OBGP-2019-190_Oncorhynchus.nerka',
            'score': '340',
            'eval': '2e-94'},
    'numTopHits': 2}
}
```

And I want to access the 'description' keys in all of the hitx sub dictionaries.

I know I could use for loops, and I  have tried the following thinking I could maybe keep it down to one for loop by looping through the recordx dictionaries and then accessing all of the 'description' keys in the hitx dictionaries within a recordx dictionary at one time, but I'm not having any success:

```
hits = dict(filter(lambda item: 'hit' in item[0], topHitsDict['record301'].items()))
seqs = dict(filter(lambda item: 'description' in item[0], hits.items()))

seqs
{}
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) does. From the docs:

> `filter(function, iterable)`:
> Construct an iterator from those elements of iterable for which function returns true.

So when you do

```
hits = dict(filter(lambda item: 'hit' in item[0], topHitsDict['record301'].items()))
```

You're essentially doing:

```
hits = {}
for item in topHitsDict['record301'].items():
    if 'hit' in item[0]:
        hits[item[0]] = item[1]
```

which gives you only the `hit*` keys from `topHitsDict['record301']`.

```
hits = {'hit1': {'description': 'OBGP-2018-240_Oncorhynchus.clarkii',
  'score': '340',
  'eval': '2e-94'},
 'hit2': {'description': 'OBGP-2017-332_Oncorhynchus.clarkii',
  'score': '340',
  'eval': '2e-94'}}
```

Instead, what you actually want is the description from those `hit*` dicts. For this, you can use `map`, and then convert the iterator to a list.

```
descriptions = list(map(lambda item: item[1]['description'], hits.items())
# descriptions: ['OBGP-2018-240_Oncorhynchus.clarkii', 'OBGP-2017-332_Oncorhynchus.clarkii']
```

This is equivalent to:

```
descriptions = []
for item in hits.items():
    descriptions.append(item[1]['description'])
```

And if you want to do this for *all* keys of `topHitsDict`, you'd have to change it up a bit. Either using a loop:

```
all_descriptions = []
for recordVal in topHitsDict.values():
    hits = dict(filter(lambda item: 'hit' in item[0], recordVal.items()))
    descriptions = list(map(lambda item: item[1]['description'], hits.items())
    # Add to all_descriptions
    all_descriptions = all_descriptions + descriptions
```

It's almost always easier to write these out as a loop first. Then you can write them as a list- or dict- comprehension, and then use `filter()` and `map()`

```
all_descriptions = []

for record in topHitsDict.values():
    for hitname, hitval in record.items():
        if "hit" in hitname:
            all_descriptions.append(hitval['description'])
```

Or as a comprehension:

```
all_descriptions = [hitval["description"] for record in topHitsDict.values() for hitname, hitval in record.items() if "hit" in hitname]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will require 2 loops to complete this unless you insist on processing every `recordxxx` key separately using 1 loop.
 And also list comprehensions are a little bit easier to read/understand than `filter`.

```
desc = [
    v["description"]
    for _, value in topHitsDict.items()
    for k, v in value.items()
    if "hit" in k
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first iterate over all the records and then for each record, check if the value is `dict` or not. If the value is dict, then search for `description` and append it to the list:

```
description = list()

for key,records in topHitsDict.items():
    for inner_key, inner_value in records.items(): 
        if type(inner_value) is dict and "description" in inner_value.keys():   
            description.append(inner_value['description'])

print(description)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `NestedDict`

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

all_descriptions = {
    'record301': {'hit1': {'description': 'OBGP-2018-240_Oncorhynchus.clarkii',
                           'eval': '2e-94',
                           'score': '340'},
                  'hit2': {'description': 'OBGP-2017-332_Oncorhynchus.clarkii',
                           'eval': '2e-94',
                           'score': '340'},
                  'numTopHits': 2,
                  'query': 'OBGP2018240_Oncorhynchus.clarkii'},
    'record302': {'hit1': {'description': 'OBGP-2018-248_Oncorhynchus.kisutch',
                           'eval': '2e-94',
                           'score': '340'},
                  'hit2': {'description': 'OBGP-2018-038_Oncorhynchus.kisutch',
                           'eval': '2e-94',
                           'score': '340'},
                  'hit3': {'description': 'OBGP-2017-271_Oncorhynchus.kisutch',
                           'eval': '2e-94',
                           'score': '340'},
                  'numTopHits': 3,
                  'query': 'OBGP2018248_Oncorhynchus.kisutch'}
}

nd = NestedDict(all_descriptions)
nd_description = nd.extract["", "", "description"]
```

Here it is the result as a dictionary

```
>>> nd_description.to_dict()
{'record301': {'hit1': {'description': 'OBGP-2018-240_Oncorhynchus.clarkii'},
               'hit2': {'description': 'OBGP-2017-332_Oncorhynchus.clarkii'}},
 'record302': {'hit1': {'description': 'OBGP-2018-248_Oncorhynchus.kisutch'},
               'hit2': {'description': 'OBGP-2018-038_Oncorhynchus.kisutch'},
               'hit3': {'description': 'OBGP-2017-271_Oncorhynchus.kisutch'}},
 'record303': {'hit1': {'description': 'OBGP-2019-056_Oncorhynchus.tshawytscha'},
               'hit2': {'description': 'OBGP-2017-356_Oncorhynchus.tshawytscha'},
               'hit3': {'description': 'OBGP-2017-052_Oncorhynchus.tshawytscha'}},
 'record304': {'hit1': {'description': 'OBGP-2019-191_Oncorhynchus.nerka'},
               'hit2': {'description': 'OBGP-2019-190_Oncorhynchus.nerka'}}}
```

If you need the values

```
>>> list(nd_description.values())
['OBGP-2018-240_Oncorhynchus.clarkii', 
 'OBGP-2017-332_Oncorhynchus.clarkii', 
 ... 
 'OBGP-2019-190_Oncorhynchus.nerka']
```